# Is there any way to get all x509 certificate attributes in tomcat filter sent by the browser?

Tags: java, tomcat, x509certificate, client-certificates

My requirement is to do authentication using x509 client-certificate instead of user-name and password.  I have two authentication mode in my application.

1. Local
2. External (Radius)

I am able to authenticate certificate in local mode by just validating the certificate in one of the tomcat filter by getting it from HTTPrequest

```
X509Certificate clientCertChains[] = (X509Certificate[]) request
                        .getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
```

For External authentication, I need to send the received certificate to External server using EAP_TLS protocol.  For making the  this happen, I need the following information from apache for that given x509 certificate.

```
TLS certificate, ( This is available in httpRequest)
TLS client_key_exchange,
TLS certificate_verify,
TLS change_cipher_spec,
TLS finished
```

My actual workflow is below:

Browser--> x509certificate-->Tomcat(Spring)-->X509certificate(EAP
-TLS)->Radius server

I am able to communicate Radius using EAP_TLS  when the x509certificate is placed in server.

```
X509Certificate clientCertChains[] = (X509Certificate[]) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
```

Comment: These are mostly TLS messages, not session 'information', and they are all gone by the time your filter is invoked. You think you need these why?

Comment: Its required to forward the x509 certificate to another external server using EAP_TLS over RADIUS.  Now all the implementation  explains x509 certificate validation on Tomcat layer. My requirement is to  forward the submited x509 from tomcat to another server.

Comment: The information you require above is part of the SSL implementation, depending upon what you have configured Tomcat with either it is JDK JSSE implementation or OpenSSL (generally). You will not be able to get any more than the certificate.

Comment: Ok.. My requirement is simple. Tomcat has to act as proxy between Browser and  AAA server . If not working  I have to write own TLS Stack implementation ?